# How to replace single quote by space from javascript to mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql

I am currently working on javascript (with Hapijs). My main mission in my company is to read data in mongodb, then feed it back into an mysql database.

My problem occurs when data in the mongodb collection contains single-quotes ('). For example, I have a data "O'Neill" and i have to put it in mysql. I found an escape() function but it replaces the single quote with "%" followed by a hexadecimal number.

I would like, if possible, to keep the single quote. Otherwise, replace it with a space.

Do you have any ideas ?

Thank you !

```
con.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    accounts.forEach((account) => {
        const sql = "INSERT INTO 2018_ACCOUNTS (ID, LOGIN, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, DATE, EVENT, UNIK) VALUES ('" + account._id + "', '" + account.login + "', '" + account.name + "', '" + account.name2 + "', '" + dateMySQL + "', " + account.evt_id + ", '" + account.unik + "')";
    con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
    });
});
```

Here is a part of my code. People with single-quote wont be added to mysql database.

Comment: Try escaping the single quote with a backslash. str.replace("'", "\'")

Comment: You're composing the query using single quotes as delimiters; use parameterized queries instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Below code

```
const sql = "INSERT INTO 2018_ACCOUNTS (ID, LOGIN, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, DATE, EVENT, UNIK) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
    con.query(sql,[account._id ,account.login ,account.name, account.name2, dateMySQL ,account.evt_id ,account.unik], function (err, result)
```

Comment: I have this error :
[log,internal,implementation,error] message: ER_WRONG_VALUE_COUNT_ON_ROW: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1, stack: Error: ER_WRONG_VALUE_COUNT_ON_ROW: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Comment: Put ` ,` before function